# UI Router default child view not activating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application I have two views, a parent view called `content-box` and a child view called `child-content`. `child-content` is tabbed content inside `content-box`. When a user lands on /settings I want the page to render the settings view in `content-box` and also load a default state in the tabbed content. I have the following code which just renders `child-content` as blank...

```
$stateProvider
    .state('silverstone.environment.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        views: {
            'content-box': {
                controller: 'EnvironmentCtrl',
                template: require('./views/configuration.html')
            },
            'child-content': {
                controller: 'EnvironmentCtrl',
                template: require('./views/settings/general.html')
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: does `content-box` & `child-content` are present on page?

Comment: @PankajParkar ... ?!

Comment: where do you have `ui-view="content-box"` & `ui-view="child-content"`

Comment: @PankajParkar in separate html views. ui-view="child-content" is contained with ./views/configuration.html (content-box)

Comment: then the other block would be `'child-content@silverstone.environment.settings': {
                controller: 'EnvironmentCtrl',
                template: require('./views/settings/general.html')
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views are siblings rather than parent child. You can update your code to following

```
$stateProvider
    .state('silverstone.environment.settings', {

        views: {
            'content-box': {
                controller: 'EnvironmentCtrl',
                template: require('./views/configuration.html')
            }

        }
    }).state('silverstone.environment.settings.view', {
        url: '/settings',
        views: {

            'child-content': {
                controller: 'EnvironmentCtrl',
                template: require('./views/settings/general.html')
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The views are not siblings, they are parent/child as described in my post... `settings` is a child of `environment`...

Comment: I changed the `environment` for reference, you can do something like I did in updated answer. And `content-box` and `chid-content` are parallel views.

Comment: for 'child-content' to render the default view the URL has to be /settings/settings this way. Both views need to be triggered on /settings.

Comment: No. The parent state i.e `silverstone.environment.settings` does not have a url to it. When you hit `/settings` it will load your parent state and then child state. You just try it once.

Comment: ...? environment.settings needs to have a url parameter, because it needs be /settings otherwise if it's blank the url is / which isn't what I want.. you're not getting this at all.

Comment: Well, it will be triggered when you hit /settings. Please try it once

Comment: I have, it works initially when you load /settings via URL but the problem I have is settings is triggered by a state link. So now when I hit the state link to trigger to the settings view, /settings is not added to the URL.

Comment: @leaksterrr - Wherever you are triggering using state, change from `silverstone.environment.settings` to `silverstone.environment.settings.view`

Comment: Ah, you're right. This has worked but surely there has to be a cleaner way to load two views simultaneously...? I'll mark you as correct

Comment: They are getting loaded simultaneously only. It is just the way of designing your application. Anyways good it worked for you

Comment: @leaksterrr yes there is way but could you answer my question in comment